# is there any way to disable a chrome extension but without hidding the icon

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i'm making a chrome extension with a toggle button that disable and enable the extension but the problem is that the extension icon hides when i click it.
i was thinking in a background extension but how I can add two extensions in the manifest.json..

Comment: What you probably want is a variable stored inside the extension storage that you will check in relevant scripts. See the documentation for chrome.storage.local.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: you can't! In a manifest.json you can only declare one extension and all the relative resources. The behaviour you want to achieve is not possible, because the icon will be removed from the chrome toolbar if an extension is deactivated, and it's not possible to change this.